# Inline numbers for report chapter sections not showing

Tags: report

I am have been trying to figure out how to write a function such that the section numbers for report chapters show in line, as well as in the table of contents. 
A MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[md]{titlesec} 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\input{introduction}
\chapter{A nice chapter title} 
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

With the introduction file being:

```
\lipsum[1]
\section{A new section}
\lipsum[2]
```

This produces the correct table of contents, with 'A new section' being labelled as 1.1, but in line it simply appears as 'A new section'. Any advice on how I can make it appear in the document as `1.1 A new section` would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think this could be the `titlesec` bug from 2016. Try to update `titlesec`

Comment: With the latest version of titlesec I have no problem.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I updated using  `sudo wget http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.sty -O /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty` and it now works perfectly. Thanks again

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because an update of the distribution solved the issue.